# setting a state with concat in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am adding an object to array with `this.setState` using `concat` function but my state stays still initial after that. There is something I missed and can't find. Here is my component.

```
const tiles = [
  {time: [0,0], text: 'first tile', color: 'red'},
  {time: [2,0], text: 'second tile', color: 'green'},
  {time: [1,3], text: 'third tile', color: 'lightblue'},
  {time: [4,6], text: 'forth tile', color: 'blue'},
  {time: [0, 23], text: 'fifth tile', color: 'grey'}
]

class CalendarGrid extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      tiles: tiles,
      showModal: false
    }

    this.addEvent = this.addEvent.bind(this);
    this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this);
    this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
  }

  addEvent(event){
    console.log(event);
    let newTiles = this.state.tiles.concat(event);
    this.setState({ tiles: newTiles });
    console.log(newTiles);
    console.log(this.state.tiles);
    this.handleCloseModal();
  }


  render(){
    const gridTiles = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 168; i++) {
      let x = i % 7;
      let y = Math.floor(i / 7);
      // console.log(this.state.tiles);
      let event = this.state.tiles.find( tile =>  tile.time[0] === x && tile.time[1] === y);
      if (event) {
        gridTiles.push(this.renderTile(i, event));
      } else {
        gridTiles.push(this.renderTile(i, null));
      }
    }

    return(
      <div className="calendar-grid">
        <div className="header">
          <div id="weekday">
            {this.getWeekDays()}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <div id="hour-numbers">
            {this.getHours()}
          </div>
          <div className="day">
            {gridTiles}
          </div>

        </div>
        <AddButton showModal={this.handleOpenModal} />
        <AddEventModal  addEvent={this.addEvent} showModal={this.state.showModal}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

In `addEvent()` function I am adding a new Object to `tiles` array but `setState` didn't modify array.

Comment: Does `addEvent` function fires?

Comment: @kinduser yes. I am getting output of `this.state.tiles` and `newTiles` there.

Comment: the `setSate` is asynchronous. When you do the `console.log(thi.state.tiles)`, probably the state wasn't updated already

Comment: Remember that `setState` is asynchro. Maybe the `console.log` function executes before state is changed? Try the callback way. `this.setState({ tiles: newTiles }, () => { do your stuff here });`

Comment: @kinduser I didn't know `setState` is asynchronous. It was a problem. Thank you